# Test operates without errors, but action isn't complete, using cypress on the React project

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I installed plugin for cypress "cypress-drag-drop".
I get 'element A' and move it to the 'Location A'.
Expected result: Modal popup appears after moving 'element A' to the 'Location A'

I use this code:

```
cy.get('.element:contains("element A")').drag('.user:contains("Location A")', {animationDistanceThreshold:true})
```

Test operates without errors.
But Modal popup doesn't appear.

By the way, behavior is strange. If I hold 'element A' and little move up, then modal popup up appears. This is what I need. Maybe some kind of expectation or state needs to be handled?
P.S.: it is React project
html:

```
<!-- Element A -->
<div class="element" >
  <span class="name">element A</span>
</div>
<!-- Location A -->
<div class="animated infinite drag-block ">
  <div class="ant-card user  ant-card-bordered ant-card-hoverable" style="width: 240px;">
    <div class="ant-card-cover">
      <div class="user-header">
        <div class="user-name">
          <span class="user">Location A</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ant-card-body">
      <div class="ant-card-meta">
        <div class="ant-card-meta-detail">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal popup-->
<div class="ant-modal-content">
  <button type="button" aria-label="Close" class="ant-modal-close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: `<span class="loction">` - is that a typo in your question, or maybe also in your program?

Comment: @Steve Zodiac, it is class="user" instead "location". I wrote "location" for better understanding. Sorry if this confused you

Comment: LOL - more important, confuses Cypress! Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: BTW React component source also useful if someone wants to reproduce. This doesn't show event that invokes Modal - is it onDrop, onChange, etc. May be able to guess, but may be wasting time.